# How to get a value from a form defined in one function, using a submit button defined in another function? - Drupal 7.x

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I'm having problems displaying a textfield form value in drupal_set_message on clicking a form button which has been defined in another function in Drupal 7.x.

My First Function contains the Form textfield only (I don't want a 'Submit' button in the first function cause of the way I want to display the form UI separately on a page)

```
function firstformfun_form($form, &$form_state) {
$form['name'] = array(
    '#title' => t(''),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#attributes' =>array('placeholder' => t('test')),
);
return $form;
}
```

The Other function consisting of other forms and a 'Submit' button:

```
function firstformfuntwo_form($form, &$form_state) {
$form['name'] = array(
    '#title' => t(''),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#attributes' =>array('placeholder' => t('test')),
);

$form['submitbtn'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Submit'),
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
        '#submit' => array('submit_name'),
    );
return $form;
}
```

I've defined a function for the 'Submit' button form as below and want it to fetch the value from the form 'Name' (textfield) in function 'firstformfun_form':

```
function submit_name($form, &$form_state) {
  $output = $form_state['values']['name'];
  drupal_set_message('Name ' .$output);
  return $page;
}
```

The result of the same only displays 'Name' in a drupal message box, but doesn't display the output value from the 'Name' text box. Could someone kindly guide me on this?

Thanks

Comment: So you want a form submit handler to access the value of a totally separate form? Not possible without some javascript AFAIK. You could have a hidden field in the second form, then when the second form is submitted, grab the value of the first forms text (via javascript) and put it into the hidden field of the second form